# Create a new column based on value of a column in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table which has a requestID column. requestId is of type String. I have three type of requestID. Let's say `bed`, `tv` and `fridge`.

- For `bed` type of request, nothing is appended in requestID. e.g. `abc123`
- For `tv` and `fridge` type of request, requestId is appended by `tv` and `fridge` respectively. e.g `abc123.tv` or `abc123.fridge`

I need to create a new table which has all columns plus column `requestType` which has entry `bed`, `tv` or `fridge`.

Input

```
| ID | RequestId     |
| 1  | abc123        |  
| 2  | abc123.tv     |   
| 3  | abc123.fridge |
```

Output

```
| ID | RequestId     |  RequestType |     
| 1  | abc123        |   bed        |
| 2  | abc123.tv     |   tv         |
| 3  | abc123.fridge |   fridge     |
```

Comment: can you show some sample data and the expected output? it is unclear what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to get the requestType column as the characters after `.` in the string. Then use `CREATE TABLE AS..SELECT..` to create a new table with all the existing columns and the newly computed one.

```
create table newtable as 
select e.*,
case when substring_index(requestID,'.',-1)=requestID then 'bed'
else substring_index(requestID,'.',-1) end as requestType
from existing_table e
```